# Як правильно зробити переклад "матрёшка"?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, from-russian

Який правильний переклад слова "матрёшка"?

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)  пропонує

> Матрёшка – матрі́йка, (рус.) матрьо́шка. *[Якщо вдуматися, то два
> головні символи Росії — матрьошка і пляшка горілки — за суттю своєю
> одне й те саме. Відкриваєш одну, а далі — друга, третя, четверта…]*

Проте в СУМ-11 та СУМ-20 немає статей "матрійка" та "матрьошка". Чи існує ще якийсь переклад данного слова, щоб був в українському словнику?

Answer (score 6):

Також існує **мотрійка**

- [Ґуґл-книги](//google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- [ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0&corpname=grac3&corpus-search-form=true)
- [Лайпцидзький корпус](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- Невідомий [Словник](//slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)

  > **Мо́трійка**, **и**, *ж*. Один з популярних українських національних сувенірів — дерев’яна лялька, якій біля ста років; існує багато версій, як і коли вона народилася, але відомо, що прообразом її послужили яскраво розфарбовані крашанки, що їх здавна точили і розписували майстри; були вони порожніми усередині, у більшу вкладалася менша.

Comment: Цікаво, що якщо вірити slovnyk.net, то наголос у _матрійка_ та _мотрійка_ різний.

Answer (score 4):

[The Russian-Ukrainian Dictionary на сайті ABBYY Linvgo Live (імовірно, побудований на базі російсько-українського словника В. Бусела видавництва «Перун»)](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> **матрёшка** матрі́йка, матрьо́шка

[Російсько-український словник у 4 т. — Т. 2. К—О / І.С. Гнатюк,С.І. Головащук, В.В. Жайворонок та ін. — К. Знання, 2012. — X, 860 с. —(Академічні словники)](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Zhaivoronok_VV/Rosiisko-ukrainskyi_slovnyk_u_4_tomakh_Tom_2_KO/):

> **матрёшка** *разг.* матрі́йка, матрьо́шка.

Отже в словниках наявні два варіанти — ті самі, що ви навели.

При цьому:

- у «Google Книгах»: [матрьошка](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) — 105 результатів, [матрійка](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0) — 0;
- у корпусі [ГРАК](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)-3: [матрьошка](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word=%22[%D0%BC%D0%9C]%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE?[%D0%BA%D1%86].*%22]) — 169 результатів, [матрійка](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word=%22[%D0%BC%D0%9C]%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE?[%D0%BA%D1%86].*%22]) — 1;
- у [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) від УМІФ: *матрьо́шка* — є, *матрійка* — нема.

Відповідно *матрьошка* вживається на два порядки частіше.

P. S.: Як [підказує інша відповідь](/a/5068), ще є варіант *мо́трійка* (через *-о-* й із іншим наголосом) — він, здається, не зафіксований у словниках, але на практиці (зокрема в посібниках з виховання дітей) уживається значно частіше за *матрі́йка* (але все-таки рідше за *матрьо́шка*; хоча варто також звернути увагу на сферу вжитку — в сучасних посібниках з виховання дітей *мо́трійка* домінує навіть над *матрьо́шка*).

Answer (score 0):

Є ще й варіант переклад у [словнику Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) (ст. 157):

> матрешка расписная - матрьошка мальована

Сайт [Dictionaries24](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0,%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0,%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) пропонує варіант "лялька" (ну або ж можна сказати "дерев'яна лялька") та "мотрійка".

[Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) перекладає лише як "матрьошка":

> Відвідуючи Росію, туристи люблять купувати сувеніри ручної роботи,
>   наприклад матрьошки.

Цікаво що:

> На той час найбільш поширеним було жіноче ім'я «Мотрона», тому нову
>   ляльку назвали зме́ншеним ім'ям «матрьошка».

В Україні ж є такі варіанти [цього імені](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD):

Мотря, Мотрона, Матрона і зменшена форма "Мотрійка".

Саме тому гадаю, що найкращим варіантом буде "мотрійка".